# Procesamiento de imagenes con WEB REST C#

Tags: c#, android-studio, sql-server, json, android-sqlite

Estoy realizando una aplicación móvil con Android Studio y la sincronizo mediante un WEB REST en C#, el problema es que al sincronizar las imágenes entre SQLite con SQL Server me manda un error en los tipos de datos en mi Web Rest. Aclaro que recibo todo en formato JSON.

BD SQL

```
CREATE TABLE EVIDENCIA (
IDEVID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
EVID varBinary(max)  NOT NULL,
FPER  varchar(25) NOT NULL
);
```

Código C#

```
public string InsertarEvidencia(Evidencia evidencia)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion);
        con.Open();
        string sql = "INSERT INTO EVIDENCIA (EVID, FPER) VALUES (@EVID, @FPER);  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        String e = evidencia.EVID.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EVID", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = e;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FPER", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = evidencia.FPER;
        var insertedID = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        string d = Convert.ToString(insertedID);
        return d;
    }

    public List<Evidencia> ObtenerEvidencia()
    {
          List<Evidencia> lista = new List<Evidencia>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion);
        con.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT IDEVID, EVID, FPER FROM EVIDENCIA";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataReader reader =  cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Evidencia cli = new Evidencia();
            cli = new Evidencia();
            cli.IDEVID = reader.GetInt32(0);
            cli.EVID = (byte[])reader["EVID"];
            cli.FPER = reader.GetString(2);
            lista.Add(cli);
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

Clase Evidencia

```
public class Evidencia
    {
        public int IDEVID { get; set; }
        public byte[] EVID { get; set; }
        public string FPER { get; set; }
    }
```

Controlador

```
public class EvidenciaController : Controller
    {
        // GET: AEvidencia/Evidencia
        EvidenciaManeager evidenciaManeager = new EvidenciaManeager();

        public EvidenciaController()
        {
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetEvidencia()
        {
            return Json(new GetEvidencia
            {
                estado = 1,
                evidencia = evidenciaManeager.ObtenerEvidencia()
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


        public JsonResult PostEvidencia(int? id, Evidencia item)
        {
            switch (Request.HttpMethod)
            {
                case "POST":

                    return Json(new PostEvidencia
                    {
                        estado = "1",
                        mensaje = "Creacion Exitosa",
                        idEvidencia = evidenciaManeager.InsertarEvidencia(item),
                    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }

            return Json(new { Error = true, Message = "Operación HTTP desconocida" });
        }
    }
```

Código Android

Database

> ```
>    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
>    String CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
>            + KEY_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
>            + KEY_FNAME +" TEXT,"
>            + KEY_POTO1  +" BLOB" + ")";
>     db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS);
> }
>
> public void addEvidencia(Contact contact){
>   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
>     ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
>
>     values.put(KEY_FNAME, contact.getFName());
>     values.put(KEY_POTO1, contact.getImage1() );
>     db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
>     db.close();
> }
> ```

class Contact

```
public Contact(String fname, byte[] img1){

    this._fname = fname;
    this._img1 = img1;

}
```

MainActivity

> ```
> private byte[] profileImage(Bitmap b) {
>
>     ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>     b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos);
>     return bos.toByteArray();
>
> }
>
> // function to get values from the Edittext and image
> private void getValues() {
>     f_name = fname.getText().toString();
>     photo1 = profileImage(bp1);
> }
>
> //Insert data to the database
> private void addEvidencia() {
>     getValues();
>
>     db.addEvidencia(new Contact(f_name, photo1));
>     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
> }
> ```

Respuesta Get
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Respuesta Post
Envio un post
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La respuesta es: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor **[edit] la pregunta** y agregue la descripción de los errores que obtiene con este código.

Comment: que dice exactamente el mensaje de error ? y en que funcionalidad lo recibes, en el get o post ?

Comment: ademas noto algo raro, porque tienes un if validando el method que sea post? eso no es correcto, si usas asp.et mvc debes poner el atributo [HttpPost] sobre el metodo para que ingrese alli solo si es post, no se pone ningun if

Comment: la clase evidencia que recibe en el action no deberia ser la misma que usas para persistir, se supone que si es un json la imagen se envie encodeada a base64, entonces en el action aplicas el decode y obtienes el byte[]

Comment: Acabo de editar mi pregunta.! @MauricioAriasOlave

Comment: En el POST @LeandroTuttini, me podrias explicar mas acerva de la base encodeada a base64, por favor

Comment: el cliente en que esta programado ? veo que pusiste android, pero es java o xamarin, lo pregunto porque deberias ver como desde el cliente encodear a base64 y tener el string del byte[] de la imagen para asignarlo al json que envias en el post

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Acabo de anexar mi codigo android

Comment: entonces android lo programas usando c# ? veo el codigo que accede a sqlite, pero como realizas el post al webapi

Comment: Mediante GSON Y Volley , tengo una clase donde realizo la sincronizacion, te parece si mejor te comparto el link de mi proyecto en Dropbox